# Configuration Babel for Webstorm 11 on Windows

Tags: windows, webstorm, babeljs

I'm having trouble getting Babel to work on my current installation of Webstorm 11 on Windows.  For some background I'm currently using Webstorm to do Angular development with a Microsoft MVC project (constraints of the project).  For the most part it has gone well but I've wanted to move to es2015.  I'm already using node package manager and the LESS transpiler with no issues.  In trying to figure out what to install I went through a number of packages:

- Babel
- Babel-cli
- Grunt-cli
- Grunt-babel
- Babel-preset-es2015

It this stage I'm okay with not using grunt; I just want to get a file to transpile before moving on to that.  I actually have Webstorm thinking the file watcher is there but it doesn't actually transpile the code.  I figured out es2015 was no longer on by default so I installed the last preset and it totally through my machine into a grind of processing tasks that maxes out my machine and only ended with an exception looking trying to for path under my project.  That path is indeed valid.  If I re-enable the file watcher it will max out my machine again.

All these seems pretty abnormal to me given I just want to enable the damn es2015 processing.  Somewhere I'm obviously doing something wrong so I'm hoping someone can give me some input in what I truly to setup Babel properly.

Thanks!

Sieg

Comment: what problem using babel as file watcher have you faced? Having Babel installed globally should normally be enough. I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: Well I ended up figuring it out but just sort of stumbled upon it.  First is setting up the scope.  By default the file watcher has project scope and it (I believe) tries to compile/process/? itself and runs in this loop that never seems to end.  Set the scope to my scripts/app folder where all my angular code is and that works great.  Second problem is the file names in the package are too long for windows and it crashes Visual Studio.  Have to move the Web Storm project root up a directory from the Visual Studio one and that is solved as well.

Comment: i see, thanks for update. Indeed, file watcher listens to changes in all javascript files in your project by default, so it will try to process node_modules as well - resulting in neverending loop. The solution is to either exclude node_modules from project (mark directory as/excluded), or set up a custom scope and set it for file watcher